# python object attribute modification

Tags: python, numpy, class, object, attributes

This is really surprising for me (and costly in terms of hours spent debugging):

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.init_value = np.array([1, 2])
    
    def func(self):
        test = self.init_value
        test[-1] = 0
        return test
test = Test()
print(test.init_value)
test.func()
print(test.init_value)
```

My questions are:

1. Is this because of the properties of numpy arrays (deep copy)?
2. Is there a way to "fix" object attributes unless I explicitly modify them?

Comment: This is because you are changing your `int_value` dynamically. Use `test = self.init_value.copy()` instead.

Comment: right, I get that. but it is still surprising for me that object attributes are "dynamically" modifiable depending on the type of the attribute (numpy array in this case). I thought they are not modifiable in default unless I explicitly say self.init_value = new_value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your Question 1):
Lets see what happens here first,

```
self.init_value = np.array([1,2])
```

a **np.array object** with the values provided is created in memory, to this the label **self.init_value** is assigned.

Now, at this step,

```
test = self.init_value
```

To the memory location pointed by **self.init_value** another label **test** is assigned. you can test this by modifying the func() as follows:

```
def func():
    test = self.init_value

    # Both these values will be same.
    print(hex(id(test)))
    print(hex(id(self.init_value)))

    test[-1] = 0
    return test
```

So when you do **test[-1] = 0** you are basically accessing the last element of the object pointed by test and changing it to value 0, since both **self.init_value** and **test** point to the same object, it gets modified.

But if you reassign some other object with the same label name, the label gets removed from the previous object and gets attached to this new object. You can verify this by checking the memory location using the code:

```
hex(id(your_label))
```

To your Question 2:

If you don't want **test** to modify **self.init_value**, modify the code to use deepcopy() as follows:

```
import copy

test = copy.deepcopy(self.init_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those weird reference vs. value issues.

Because self is a reference, your test variable is a reference to self.init_value...

So you ARE modifying the attribute. @matfux’s solution has your variable store a copy of self.init_value rather than a reference to it.

Honestly, a tricky bit in most OOP situations.

Comment: yeah, as you said, the tricky thing for me is that "self is a reference". I was aware of dynamic modification in situations that b = a (a is a numpy array), then changes in b will modify a. I just never thought the same thing applies here (again, because I didn't realize that "self is a reference")